# sliding panel from bottom like Google Play Music using View pager + RecycleView inside the main content

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, slidingpanelayout

I want to make sliding panel from bottom like Google Play Music so i am using Umano Library but View pager inside the main content not scrollable. Please help me out.
I have view Pager which loads data from server and set in recycler view but the view pager tabs not scrolling and the sliding layout data not showing.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout             
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</FrameLayout>

<!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dragView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rllayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cart_icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cart_icon" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rllayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/no_of_items"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="quiz_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="quiz_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/taxes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="plus taxes" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCheckOut"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_10dp"
            android:text="Check Out" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/sliding_panel_layout"></include>

</LinearLayout>
```

Sliding_panel_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<com.satkarrestro.classes.AutoResizeTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Ready to Proceed"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_15sp" />

<com.satkarrestro.classes.AutoResizeTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCategoryName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_10dp"
    android:text="abcdef"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_10sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></ListView>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tbSum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: "Which loads data from server" and "not showing"... Are you sure you are actually getting data from the server?

Comment: actually i solved my problem but another problem is that on scrolling the item data will change or on click item they take the other postion item data. so how is it solved . I edited my question

Comment: It doesn't appear you saved the edits to the question

Comment: @cricket_007 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269607/in-recycler-view-on-scrolling-the-data-item-position-will-change-or-on-click-i

Comment: please see this ling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269607/in-recycler-view-on-scrolling-the-data-item-position-will-change-or-on-click-i